# Can't even print out an array

Tags: arrays, printf

I'm trying to print out an array but its not working.

Currently using sublime text 2 and node build, not sure if I have to declare something before writing code.

Here's the code:

```
String card[] = new card[2]
card[0] = "Ace";
card[1] = "two"; 
card[3] = "three";  

for(int i=0; i< card.length; i++)
{
    system.out.print(""+card[i]);
}
```

The debugger gave me the following result:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {   String card[] = new card[2]


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: please check the language. is it java (more likely) or javascript (unlikely, because of types)

Comment: @NinaScholz: But the error message shows them clearly trying to run it in a JavaScript environment.

Comment: Well running Java inside a Javascript environment usually does cause errors.

Comment: Yep. Seems more of a problem with the transpiler, whatever it might be.

Comment: card[3] ?? check that. it should be card[2]. And not system.out.print it is System.out.print and use new String[3] instead of new card[2]

Comment: system.out.print, doesn't look like something from any transpilier I've used, but does look like a built in function from Java.

Comment: Ray Lu - You're confusing Java with JavaScript. They're completely different languages, with a little bit of syntactic similarity. That's clearly meant to be Java code, but you're trying to run it in a JavaScript (specifically, NodeJS) environment. So either run it in a Java environment (there are errors, but you'll figure them out as the compiler tells you about them and you study), or write JavaScript code to run in the environment you're using. We can't guess which you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little rusty. I am indeed trying to write Js code but I got it confused with Java, thanks guys for cleaning it up for me. Now to somehow get the for loop to work +_+

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up javascript with java or another language.

Javascript doesn't use explicit types in the declaration, so to declare a new array you would write `var array = [];`

The printing to output is also more Java than javascript. Rather than `system.out.print` you would use `console.log` which writes to standard out. You can write to standard error with `console.error`

For js your example would look like this:

```
var card = []; // declare the variable card as an array
card[0] = "Ace";
card[1] = "two"; 
card[3] = "three";  

for(var i=0; i< card.length; i++)
{
    console.log(card[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? He said he's using node and tagged the question as javascript. With both those two things coinciding, it's safer to assume an attempt at JS rather than Java

Comment: Thank you, although it didnt work because for some reason the i in the for loop was not recognized, I tried just console.log(card[0]); 

and got "ace" which atleast is pointing towards the right direction.

Comment: Ok I figured out the for loop problem too, needed to initialize my iterators. Which you already did changing from int = 0 to var = 0. Thanks again.